# AWK insert line for certain condition in a condition

Tags: awk

I hope I choose my title right. I am no programmer and the terms in this field I still have to learn.

My problem is that I have to insert new lines with some records in a /find/ {} condition.

Here is the example input:

```
1;2;3;4;
b;2;3;4;
txn;2;3;4;
a;2;3;4;
;;;;
b;2;3;4;
b;2;5;4;
b;2;3;4;
;;;;
c;2;3;4;
;;;;
```

Here you see why I use the /txn/{} - the original input has a number of lines I do not want to print before the part I am interested in. Only lines "after" the first occurence of txn.

I want to insert two new lines if $1=b and $3=5 are. 
Moreover I need to print $0 plus a new field eg. $5 in the first new line and print $0 and a new field into $6 for example. (Eventually empty line should be skipped.)

OUTCOME shall be

```
a   2   3   4
b   2   3   4       
b   2   5   4       
    2   5   4   6   
    2   5   4       7
b   2   3   4       
c   2   3   4
```

My starting snippet

```
BEGIN { OFS=FS=";"}

    /^txn/,/^$/ {
    ###### tries to insert line ######
    # eg. if ($1=="b") "\n" ;
    ##################################
    print $1 FS "custom text" FS $3 FS "custom text" FS $5 $6 }
```

Best awk I could manage myself is:

```
if ($1=="b" && $3=="5") {print; print $1 FS "custom text" FS $3 FS "custom text" FS $5 $6 ;next}1}
```

This inserts one line but does not print the other lines.

Other code snippets I found via search and I understand only partially but who neverthelesse did not work for me are:

```
###### tries to insert line ######
last~/b/" && $3=="3" {print "6\n7 "} {last=$1} 1
$1~/b/ {p=1} p && $3=="3"{print "6"; print "7"; p=0} 1'
/txn/ { $0 = $0 RS "6" RS "7"};
for $1'/b/ {$0 = $0 RS "6" RS "8"};
print nl $0; nl="\n"
if ($1~/b/)  print $3 FS "works     INSERTED LINE", "\n" ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=";";OFS="\t"}
    f && $1!=""{$1=$1; print}
    $1=="b" && $3==5 && f{$1="";$5=6; print; $5=""; $6=7; print}
    $1=="txn"{f=1}' file
```

you get,

```
a   2   3   4   
b   2   3   4   
b   2   5   4   
    2   5   4   6
    2   5   4       7
b   2   3   4   
c   2   3   4
```

Comment: I works! Could you be so super kind to translate your awk to me? All except the 1st and 3rd line are far behind my understanding :) For my purpose I had to change to OFS=";" and it still works.

Comment: See the [GNU Awk Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields) for an explanation of $1 = $1

Comment: @prestalearner if you wanted your output to be separated by `;`s why would you show your desired output separated by something else (spaces) in your question? I don't understand your thought process.... "I want a banana" -> "Here's a banana" -> "OK but I actually wanted a grape". I had actually upvoted your question as I thought it was clear until I read this!

Comment: I assumed that it would be easier to copy ; separated input from here for testing. I also assumed that it would be easer to gather my wished output if it would be visually attractive alligned by spaces/tabs. I am not programmer nor do I use Linux. I had a hard time to gather me a way to test AWK and learn by trail&error and having all the handbook / manuals of awk at hand doing this in Windows. Actually I can script now in a texteditor and see input / output via a nice tool with a bit less typing than you might though I know you are professionally teaching and coding. I had  best intentions.

Comment: Jose, I am so much nearer to my goal cleaning my original input and your solution was so helpful to my answer. I read the chapter in the linked  manual and still have problems with that. It is a totally different level that that I learned the last 3 days. I stumbled now about an issue and do not get it. If I change parts of your snipped it doesnt work anymore: $2=="2" && $3==3{$1="";$5=6; print; $5=""; $6=7; print} I just changed $3==3 cause of my orginal input and not the example. I did not expect this and I still do not undstand your code totally -->   $1=="txn"{f=1} this is most tricky tome

Comment: @prestalearner use `$2==2 && $3==3 && f` instead of `$2=="2" && $3==3` i fixed this in post ...... `f` is only a variable `f=1` is same that `f` set `true` value